# How to find load of the server in IBM AIX?

Tags: performance, operating-system, load, aix

I'm using IBM AIX 5.3

How to get the load of the server for my OS ?

Other than **TOPAS** command what can be used ?

Answer (score -1):

you can try nmon for monitoring your system

http://nmon.sourceforge.net/pmwiki.php

you can also use it to collect data by using crontab